# GameObject Prefabs floating away

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two sphere GameObjects as prefabs. They have rigidbodies attached. I want them to stay put on a surface but interact with each other when they collide (push each other around, bounce off each other, blah blah). However, in the game view, when I drag in a prefab, and the rigidbody "use gravity" checkbox is turned off, the objects float away! I don't want this so I turned on "use gravity." Now, they get placed into the scene but still take a long time to settle down into the floor and when I drag them around, they can still kind of float around there. How do I just get them to stay on the surface but interact with each other?

I have tried doing something like

```
(Get-the-GameObject).GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

but that doesn't do anything.

In the picture, you can see that I have placed the sphere on the floor but it has floated away!  In the Physics editor, the gravity is set to Y-component of -9.81.

Edit: I have made the scales of my spheres smaller to about 5 and it'll drop down into the floor and start sliding to the left.  The floor is not tilted in any way so I am wondering why it is sliding around now...

Edit:

Spheres are instantiated by clicking on a box with that color that you want and dragging it on the desk space and releasing.  Once released is when it starts floating away/sliding. Here is the code that does that.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab_to_instatiate, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    // Code to make an atom follow the mouse cursor
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit2;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit2, Camera.main.farClipPlane))
    {
        float oldY = transform.position.y;
        clone.transform.position = new Vector3(hit2.point.x, oldY, hit2.point.z);
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit 2: The best way to describe what is going on is if I provide a video.  Link here: https://vimeo.com/185419058

I click a box with atoms, hold down the mouse button to drag it into the desk area and release to drop it.  However, as I drag, the video shows the atom bouncing around like crazy even if my mouse is stationary.  Then, when I release, it starts sliding around.  I just want to click, drag, and place it in a position without getting all these crazy effects.  This works how I want to if I remove rigidbodies on all my prefab-ed atoms.  However, I want to be able to use rigidbodies because I want atoms to interact when they come into proximity with one another.

Comment: What is the scale of the objects relative to the world scale? If they're giant, then any effects of gravity will seem a bit "floaty".

Comment: My spheres have scales ranging from 40-50

Comment: Are there any other scripts that govern the movement of the spheres? Can we see the scene hierarchy/properties for the spheres?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my question.

Comment: On top of scale/size there's bounciness of the different surfaces (physics materials), mass/interpolation/drag/etc of rigidbodies as well as several other settings affecting "physical properties". You should understand all those and share all the settings you have if the problem persists (EDIT: and you should do all "physics related" actions in FixedUpdate())

Comment: Okay, scaling everything down didn't work.  My rigidbodies attached to these prefab-ed spheres are: mass = 1, drag = 0, angular drag = 0, use gravity is on, is kinematic is off, interpolate is none, collision detection is discrete.

Comment: @Mark - I don't do anything in my Update() nor FixedUpdate() methods yet because they are all in OnMouseDrag methods.

Comment: Also no physics material added? neither to the surface where your balls lay nor to the balls? Physics settings (project settings) are the default? What if you give a bit more mass to the balls? Let's say 20. Or for testing, 200.

Comment: @Mark - Physics settings are default.  Tried increasing mass and did not have an effect.  I updated my question to include a video of the issue which should explain the situation a bit better.

Comment: Oh lol. You forgot to add initially the most important details :DD Anyway. You got an answer, it seems it helped you so cheers ;) Have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to control an object which is under control of the Physics engine. Just like an empire has 2 kings, it is obvious that there will be a war or conflicts.

Let take it one step further, Physics engine gets updated every FixedUpdate(), 0.02s default settings, and your OnMouseDrag() is executed every frame.

> OnMouseDrag is called every frame while the mouse is down.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html

In your `OnMouseDrag()` you are setting the position by using `transform.position`, it is a non-physics method. I suggest you try `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` or `Rigidbody.position`. I haven't tried it yet, I often prefer to write my own physics simulation because Unity's is nut.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

If that didn't fix your problem you could try turning off the `rigidbody`, `rigidbody.enabled = false`, while `OnMouseDrag()` is in effect to avoid conflicts and when you release the mouse, turn it back on to return control to the physics engine.

Comment: Using `Rigidbody.MovePosition` did not work for me but your suggestion to turn off the `rigidbody` and re-enable it entirely while using regular `transform.position` moving worked!  Note: Disabling `rigidbody` entails setting `isKinematic` to true and vice versa.  Now everything works! I can click to instantiate a new atom, drag it to an appropriate place, release it and it falls down nicely and remains there.  Perfect answer for me.

Comment: Yep, I forgot a thing that disabling rigidbody while moving an object will cause a serious overheat to the system because it assumes a collider without rigidbody is a static collider (won't move). Toggling isKinematic is better :D

Comment: @noblerare so these are atoms! nice! let me know when you released the title ;)